# Mixed logic gates AC or weird multiplexer

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer

I was thinking of ways to control 2 devices each with 3 bits or more input.
Ideally this can be done with one inverter and 6 AND ports. Or a *weird* multiplexer. Of course it can be done with 2 74LS or similar, but I was wondering if a single chip that does this exists and what it is named.

Think of the digital equivalent of this ancient device below.
Which leads me to the question: do such mixed gates IC exist? I know about the configurable ones, but they serve a different purpose.

Thanks!

[image: ancient 9 line A/B switch]

Comment: Why would the multiplexer need to be "weird"? This can be done with one or more multiplexer ICs. Yes these exist. For example the HEF4053: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4053B.pdf  You would need a couple of these.

Comment: Ah thanks, I need to clarify the question. Yes you can do it with 2 ICs (inverter + AND ports), I was wondering if a single IC exists. Looking at the one you linked.

Comment: Sorry, asking for recommendations of specific products is off-topic here.

Comment: I was not asking recommendation about specific products. The question was very generic  about the existence of digital ports like the one I am looking forward.

Comment: Also consider the ancient CMOS 4016 quad bilateral switch and it's many variants.

Comment: The 4016 and 4053 do the purpose wonderfully! And they come even in DIP packages for easy prototyping.

Comment: The 4066 is a useful alternative to the 4016 too. Otherwise look for 'analog switches' in the catalogs, they make them for many different purposes.